# Make an old project to use nuget package manager and create package.config file

Tags: .net, git, nuget, .net-3.5, nuget-package

I am currently working in an old solution that didn't used nuget to get its packages in the past but i am trying to add it to software delivery pipeline(git source control) and its failing to restore packages. The way it works is, it restores the packages in the build process and in my case it cannot find a way to restore the packages. Git Ignores the bin folder and hence all the packages are not checked in source control. I can remove the git ignore on bin folder but before that I wanted to make sure if there is an easy way to add packages to like a package.config file and restored at build process. Bottom line is I want this old .Net 3.5 project to use Nuget instead of how's it working right now by referencing in csproj file from the bin folder.

Comment: using nuget packages does not suppose including any binaries to vcs. Please clarify what you are trying to do

Comment: The question title sounds like your solution is not using NuGet, but your first sentence says restore fails, which means it is. If there's a restore error, please show us what the error message is. Elsewhere you talk about the bin folder. But if one project needs the bin folder of a different project, you probably want project references, not NuGet packages. If you could [provide us with an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it would be much easier to understand and help you.

Comment: @zivkan My solution is not using Nuget but the build process on the server is using nuget package restore to get packages. GIT is ignoring the package using .gitIgnore file. I am looking for easy way to migrate these package references from my CSPROJ file to Package.Config file.

Comment: ok, so when you say "bin folder", you don't actually mean the output folder of a .NET project that is built/compiled? In whatever you used before git, someone manually created a folder called bin and copied dlls in there? Or you already have a `packages.config` file that needs to be restored before opening the Visual Studio solution?

Comment: Its an old solution so I am not sure how they got the references in the bin folder. Manually copied is my guess as well. The solution doesn't have a package.config file and that's my end goal to create one with the references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is:

1. Delete the folder with all the dlls
2. For each compile error due to missing namespace/class, use Visual Studio's Package Manager to install the necessary package. Note, it will be faster to use the Package Manager Console, rather than the UI, particularly if you have a large number of projects and/or packages. Just remember to select the correct project in the project selection drop down menu.
3. Open each project file one by one in a text editor (or you can unload the project in VS's solution explorer and then edit, but I find it faster to just use VSCode) and delete any line starting with `<Reference` and the include path is to the bin directory you deleted earlier (leave the .NET Framework references). You could set MSB3106 as a warning to treat as an error to make it easier to find all the instances of

If you're using Visual Studio 2017, I encourage you to consider using PackageReference instead of packages.config. There are [several benefits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference#benefits-of-using-packagereference), not to mention that SDK style projects (required by .NET Core) no longer support packages.config. I also recommend switching to SDK style projects if possible for project types that can (not all can, but any class libraries and console apps generally can without issue).